# Save the Angular CLI build logs to a file

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I've checked [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and there's no option that can be passed to the Angular CLI to save logs to a file. I've tried this:

```
ng build |& tee output.txt
```

The problem is that the resulting file is crashing my Atom editor and in Geany it's unreadable, because of the characters like [BS], [ESC](their removal messes up formatting and the file is still unreadable).

Could you please share your tricks, good sirs?

Comment: I tried this and works for me `ng build & >> log.txt `

Comment: @Majid, your command gives an empty file (Ubuntu 16.04), but thanks anyway

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov you ever figure out a way to do this without producing an unreadable mess?

Comment: @mtpultz, no, sorry, sir

Answer (score 26):

Try

```
ng build &> log.txt
```

Comment: Tried and got "The syntax of the command is incorrect"  Tried without the '&'.  Seemed to work initially but it turned the cmd window red and log.txt was empty.

Comment: @user3217883 what shell are you using? > is the default redirect operator in bash and & ensures that both stdout and stderr should be redirected. If you use > only, it would not redirect any errors to your file. Both variants should technically work without trouble.

Comment: I was a cmd shell. I also tried a power shell. I didn't think about using a bash shell.

Comment: for windows try ng build > log.txt 2>&1

Comment: @fluf what is the extra `2>&1` on the end? It seems to do the trick anyway!

Comment: @Caltor Looks like [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/what-does-21-mean) explains that.